# Highlight a current active playlist item in JWPlayer 5.9

Tags: javascript, css, jwplayer

I am trying to highlight a currently played playlist item in jwplayer. I am using version 5.9. If anyone has an experience and have probably done that please respond and advice me how to do this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the player's "frontcolor" and "lightcolor" flashvars.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12536/configuration-options#colors

Here is a demo - http://bit.ly/VvF6VJ